# dtplyr and count conflict on a data.table object

Tags: r, count, data.table, dplyr, dtplyr

It seems that when `dtplyr` is installed with `dplyr` and `data.table` I get this issue

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)

dt1 = mtcars

# works as expected
dt1 %>% count(cyl)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#     cyl     n
#   <dbl> <int>
# 1     4    11
# 2     6     7
# 3     8    14

# used to work but not now
setDT(dt1) %>% count(cyl)

# Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

That used to work, but not at the moment. Why is this happening?

Also, when I run this process without `dtplyr` it works, but without having the advantages that `dtplyr` offers.

I'm using up to date versions of those packages (`dplyr` 0.7.0, `data.table` 1.10.4, `dtplyr` 0.0.2).

Comment: I think you're looking for https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr/issues

Comment: Thanks for the info and the edit.

Comment: Your code works for me. You might want to try loading the packages in a different order. It could be due to conflicts in their dependencies.